# Reconstruct a matrix from its traces

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, traces

In my research I came across the following problem. Let $A$ be a symmetric  and $\Gamma$ be a diagonal $n\times n$ matrices. The eigenvalues of $A$ are known $\lambda_1,\ldots\lambda_n$. The traces $\mathrm{Tr}(A^k\,\Gamma)=t_k$, $k\in\mathbb{N}$ are also known, $\Gamma$ is given. Can $A$ be found based on this information? If yes, how? While I am curious about the general $n$ case, information on $n=3$ would be most valuable.  Any reference would be greatly appreciated.

P.S.

- From the answer of Francesco Polizzi it is known that the reconstruction is not possible when there is an orthogonal matrix $M$ that commutes with $\Gamma$.  Fortunately, in the case of interest, this situation can be excluded. Specifically, *it is known that diagonal entries of $\Gamma$ are all distinct and positive.* By this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1697991/do-diagonal-matrices-always-commute), $\Gamma$ then commutes only with diagonal matrices.
- user44191 suggested that $B=M^{-1}AM$ ($M$-nonsingular) will have the same traces as $A$. However, apart from a trivial $\pm1$ possibility, which can be excluded by a proper sign convention, the new matrix $B$ is no longer symmetric. Thus, it leaves the question open.

Comment: It is not true for $\Gamma=I$. Since $Tr(A^k)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \lambda_{i}^k$, no additional information can be retrieved besides the eigenvalues (which are already given).

Comment: If $B$ is a nonsingular matrix that commutes with $\Gamma$, then $B^{-1}AB$ will have the same traces; assuming that $\Gamma$ has distinct eigenvalues, these $B$ are arbitrary diagonal matrices. It may still be possible to determine the $C_G(\Gamma)$-conjugacy class $A$ belongs to in $\mathbb{M}_n$ (though I haven't checked fully).

Comment: @user44191 Can you please elaborate about the conjugacy classes?

Comment: @JosiahPark Indeed $\Gamma=I$ is somewhat a special case. The problem may also be ill posed for $\Gamma$ in the vicinity of $I$.  It is my hope, however, solutions may be found for some $\Gamma$.

Comment: @yarchik Allowing for multiple $\Gamma$'s allows for a positive answer. For instance for $n=3$ if one takes $\Gamma_{i}=e_{i}e_{i}^{T}$, $i=1,\dots,3$ one can recover $A$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately even the generic situation is bad. Since we know the eigenvalues, we should search for the orthonormal system of eigenvectors $v_i$ of $A$. We have ($e_i$ is the standard basis)
$$
Tr(A^k\Gamma)=\sum_i\left[\sum_j\gamma_j \langle v_i,e_j\rangle^2\right]\lambda_i^k
$$
so, in effect, you have the knowledge of $\sum_j\gamma_j \langle v_i,e_j\rangle^2$ ($i=1,2,3$). However, these three values are not independent: since the matrix $(\langle v_i,e_j\rangle^2)_{ij}$ is bistochastic, their sum is just $Tr \Gamma$, so you have only $2$ independent equations, while the orthogonal matrices form a 3D manifold. Thus in the generic case you should expect a continuous 1-parametric family of solutions.

Comment: Yes, this fully answers my question. Just a short clarification question, do you have any insight on what kind of 1-parameter freedom would that be? If we talk about the orthogonal matrices realizing a rotation in 3d space, would it be possible to say something like, the axis of rotation can be determined, but not the angle?

Comment: One may expect a 1-parametric family of solutions, however, that is because you allow them to be complex. $A$ is symmetric and, therefore, eigenvectors should be real. Imposing this additional condition may lead to a finite number of solutions in some cases. Do you agree with this?

Comment: @yarchik No. I did purely real analysis. Nothing was complex. The *real* orthogonal matrices are a 3D manifold and the 2 equations were real as well.

Answer (score 5):

I do not think you can reconstruct $A$ just from this information.

Take $\Gamma=I_n$, let $M$ be any orthogonal $n \times n$ matrix and set $B={}^tMA M$.

Then $A$ and $B$ are two similar (symmetric) matrices, and so all their positive powers $A^k$ and $B^k$ have the same eigenvalues (and in particular the same trace).

Comment: $\Gamma=I_n$ is somewhat special. What if we do not assume from onset that gamma is the identity matrix?

Comment: In the general case, take as $M$ a (non-identical) orthogonal matrix commuting with $\Gamma$. Then
$${}^tM(A^k \Gamma) M = B^k ({}^tM \Gamma M) = B^k \Gamma,$$
so $A^k \Gamma$ and $B^k \Gamma$ are similar and the same argument applies.

Comment: Can one always find a (non-identical) orthogonal matrix $M$ that commutes with $\Gamma$? For me it is not obvious, scaling and rotation typically do not commute.

Comment: Ok, let's say that if the centralizer of $\Gamma$ contains a (non-identical) orthogonal matrix, then the reconstruction of $A$ is not possible. I did not check whether this is always the case for all diagonal matrices.

Comment: Yes, it is then a right statement. It gives a class of $\Gamma$ when the reconstruction is not possible.

Comment: @yarchik A diagonal matrix with only $\pm1$ entries is orthogonal and commutes with any diagonal matrix. For a diagonal matrix with only distinct entries, I suspect that these are the only orthogonal matrices that commute.

Comment: @M.Winter Diagonal matrices with only distinct entries only commute with other diagonal matrices, and the only diagonal orthogonal matrices are the ones you listed.